# Modify field issues via global in python

Tags: python

If I have two files a, b, defined in file a as follows:

```
x = 10 # global variable

def modify_global_variable():
  global x # Use the global keyword to declare x as the global variable
  x = 20 # to modify the value of the global variable x
```

The b file is defined as follows:

```
from a import x

modify_global_variable()
print(x)
```

At this time to execute the b file, then how much is the x output？
My output result is that: 10
But make the b file as follows：

```
import a

a.modify_global_variable()
print(a.x)
```

At this point, I run the b file again, and the output result is 20.
Any friend to help me to answer, this is why？？
Thank you！！

Comment: How can you call `modify_global_variable` from `b` if it is defined in `a` and you haven't imported it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because:

```
from a import x
```

Is essentially equivalent to:

```
import a
x = a.x
del a
```

So *you are creating a new global variable in the module that executes that import statement.*

The original `a.x` variable is still there, and your `modify_global_variable()` function modifies it in both cases. It's just not the same variable as `b.x`.

Consider the following scenario with dictionaries:

```
>>> a = {'x': 10}
>>> b['x'] = a['x']
>>> print(a, b)
{'x': 10} {'x': 10}
>>> a['x'] = 20 # your modify_global_variable does this
>>> print(a, b)
{'x': 20} {'x': 10}
```

Essentially, your modules work the same way (indeed, their namespaces are literally `dict` objects that you can get with `globals()` from within the module or, with a reference to the module, say you `import module`, then just `module.__dict__` or `vars(module)`.